# What is the data tag used to check success on a command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to do test to see if a command block has succeeded but the command in the commandblock does not emit a comparator signal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command blocks are of Tile Entity type "Control". According to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Tile_Entity_Format):

> **Control** has these additional fields:

> - **Command:** The command to issue to the server.

- **SuccessCount:** Represents the strength of the analog signal output by redstone comparators attached to this command block. Only updated when the command block is activated with a redstone signal.
- **LastOutput:** The last line of output generated by the command block. Still stored even if the gamerule commandBlockOutput is false. Appears in the GUI of the block when right-clicked, and includes a timestamp of when the output was produced.
- **TrackOutput:** 1 or 0 (true/false) - Unknown.

Since your command does not yield a redstone signal, the only way to detect the outcome of the command block via data tags is to read **LastOutput**.